# Are there perfective verbs that only accept perfective infinitives?

Tags: глаголы, вид

The following perfective verbs are said to only accept perfective infinitives.

```
забыть - to forget
успеть - to manage, have time
удаться - to manage, succeed
суметь - to be able to manage
получиться - to succeed, manage
```

For example:

```
Я забыл купить марки. - I forgot to buy stamps.
```

Is that right that they only accept perfective infinitives as their dependencies? If yes, what is the logic behind that?

Comment: Can you please clarify what exactly you are asking about? Explanation of what exactly you are looking for?

Comment: The logic as to why those verbs behave like that.

Comment: I'm sorry then, I will have to leave it closed. Asking why verbs have specific feature is too broad.

Comment: Those verbs on your list sometimes allow imperfective infinitives after them, e.g. _Однако, я сделал многое, и сделал бы больше, если бы сумел все сказать и **сумел говорить** без боязни его обидеть._ (Письмо от Страхова Н. Н. к Толстому Л. Н., 30 июня 1880 г., 
http://tolstoy-lit.ru/tolstoy/pisma-tolstomu/pisma-strahova/letter-107.htm) Here _говорить_ is imperf. inf. following _сумел_ from your list. Or this: _Ты **забыл говорить** о себе, Ты **забыл говорить** о высоком_. (From [Google Books](https://bit.ly/3xLeM2d)).

Comment: if you will edit question to state something like "is it indeed the case and this verbs can not be used with imperfective verbs at all", then I can reopen it and @YelowSky would be able to add  an answer.

Comment: "Yellow Sky" - "Ты забыл говорить о себе, Ты забыл говорить о высоком." - but this version sound like as the Simple Tense style... "я забыл как плавать"...

Answer (score 1):

No, the imperfect form of the verb can also be used if we show the time period:

- Я все время забывал покупать марки.
- Я никогда не успевал приходить вовремя.

Thus, we mean a repetitive action. But if there was one action (I did it and that's all), then the perfect form of the verb is obligatory.

Comment: You changed the verbs' aspect. The OP asked, if the *perfective* verbs (e.g. забыть) could only take a perfective infinitive. Your examples use imperfective (забывать). So I think this doesn't answer the question